# Fusion table map view

Tags: google-maps, view, google-fusion-tables

I am very impressed with Kathryn Hurley's article https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/data_gathering and I required the same type of application in fusion table map views. That is, I have created a fusion table layer with table ID=xxxxx where the data from multiple sources will inserted. Is it possible to create a filtered view for different data providers who can view only their set of data in the map?

Comment: Where do you want to use the map, externally? How do you authenticate the data-providers?

Comment: @Dr.Molle - I want use that map in one of my application. When a particular user logs in to my application using google id, he should see only his part of data from the fusion table.

Comment: see the answer of Burton449, you may filter the displayed data by a particular column(e.g. a colum that gives you the relation between an user and his data)

Comment: @Dr.Molle - Also I required the same data gathering in my another application which I given here: http://jsfiddle.net/ygrmr/ Here I required to load the particular data for a particular user in drill down.

Comment: When you select a map-view you get the needed source via `publish->get html and javascript` . This source contains the javascript-code that creates the layer. You may use a query like shown in the post of Burton449 to filter the rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of query of fusiontable layer provided by [google maps doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
   select: 'address',
   from: '1d7qpn60tAvG4LEg4jvClZbc1ggp8fIGGvpMGzA',
   where: 'ridership > 5000'
  }
});
```

You can make different queries on the same fusiontable layer in different methods or different maps.

Comment: [Please visit this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241029/fusion-table-data-gathering-and-view) and please help.