# Fusion table data gathering and view

Tags: google-maps, view, google-fusion-tables

I went through [this link](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2584135?hl=en) and I required the same idea in my application.
I have a Master fusion table with table id = xxxxxxxxxxxxx and I made several views from that table for different departments. Now Is it possible to access fusion table map layer of only their view for perticular department? (ie, when a person of a perticular department signs in with his account, he should able to view the map of his data only)

Comment: please post your code if you want help

Comment: @Burton449 - [Code added in this link](http://jsfiddle.net/C26gN/)

Comment: you have many possibilities. First create a registration page login/account/password ect... then create different map for each user with different options, or use a web framework to manage it. Your question is too large...

Comment: I want a single map which can be handled by queries.

Comment: Ok its possible, but each user would have possible access to the queries of other users just by looking in the code page. Use javascript for the queries. if (user == "john"){ display table with query..